# Unusual behaviour with json_encode php

Tags: java, android

My server API receives messages from clients in a post request, stores them in a table, and then sends the message to the intended client using firebase notification through a curl request.

If I send a message to my server from my android app, example `This message doesn't work` (has a single quote), the server receives that and stores it in the database, but I have used `addslashes()` so that it gets stored OK without breaking out of my query. When I look at the database, I see `1  |  user_1  | user_2  |  This message doesn't work` (Note the single quote is there)

Then, I build an array with the data I want to send to the intended client:

```
    //We are going to insert the new message into the database, assign all the variables a shortname
    $from_id = $user['id'];
    $to_id = $_POST['to_user_id'];
    $body = $_POST['message_body'];
    $from_name = $user['firstname'] . ' ' . $user['lastname'];

    //Build a query to insert into the `user_messages` table
    $query = "INSERT INTO `user_messages` (`from_user_id`,`to_user_id`,`message_body`) VALUES ('". $from_id ."','". $to_id ."','". addslashes($body) ."')";

    //Execute the query to insert the new message
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    //Now we want to proceed to send the message on to its destination, get the destination installation ID
    $query = "SELECT * FROM application_tokens WHERE user_id=" . $to_id;
    $tokens[] = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, $query), MYSQLI_ASSOC)['application_token'];

    //With the token, we want to build the string of data that gets sent to the FCM notifications server
    $NotificationData = array(
            "data" => array(
                    "notification_type" => "message",
                    "from_user_id" => $from_id,
                    "from_user_name" => $from_name,
                    "sent_time" => date('H:i'),
                    "message_body" => $body,
            ),
            "registration_ids" => $tokens,
    );

    //Broadcast the message
    SendFCM($notifications_key, $NotificationData);

    function SendFCM($notifications_key, $NotificationData){
            $command = "curl -X POST --Header 'Authorization: key=". $notifications_key  ."' --Header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '" . json_encode($NotificationData) . "' 'http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'";

            shell_exec($command);

            file_put_contents("/var/www/html/MobileAppAPI/data.log", $command);
    }
```

but for some reason, even though my data.log file contains

```
curl -X POST --Header 'Authorization: key=AIzaSyCUQWJWypXPXxDV2s3wfNPprx5Kiu0uvho' --Header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"data":{"notification_type":"message","from_user_id":"7","from_user_name":"test device2","sent_time":"15:56","message_body":"test\\'"},"registration_ids":["cvmM2CufUWE:APA91bGrEgT6oMoedJK-CxZDDRCu356E5MteYHppqFxBU4DWOaNOU6sVAZ1xzaRfSDtUdbRpGz1WExuMMELGA6vit-d9_Sxim_OhRvESGRzNPJp-5DMzuavMKbwFIPCSASed2GJKLjg8"]}' 'http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
```

more specifically

```
"message_body":"test\\'"
```

which appears to be correctly escaped, the message is never sent to the client. In fact, I don't think the command gets executed, as when I run the contents of the data log manually, it gets stuck with a missing '"' somewhere.

Have I escaped the single quote incorrectly? Messages without single quotes come through OK.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this would be the cause but a best practice note, you should use `mysqli_escape_string($conn_obj, $string)` instead of `addslahses()` as addslashes doesn't know anything about the encoding type that MySQL will use, whereas using the mysqli_escape_string will ensure that the encoding that the connection is used is used in the escaped string

Comment: OK - yes I have now switched my insert to use that instead, but it doesn't make any difference to sending out the notification, as you said.

Comment: You can get the return value of what shell_exec did, it would likely contain what happened. Although using PHPs shell_exec to do a curl command is a bad idea. There is a PHP curl library which is much better suited for doing this and will be far easier to check against for any errors in the request. Maybe http://codular.com/curl-with-php will help

Comment: `json_encode` is applying json escaping rules which are not necessarily suitable for command-line parameters. I would probably avoid using `shell_exec`.